# Correlation formula explanation needed d3.js

Tags: underscore.js

```
function getCorrelation(xArray, yArray) {
  alert(xArray);
  alert(yArray);
  function sum(m, v) {return m + v;}
  function sumSquares(m, v) {return m + v * v;}
  function filterNaN(m, v, i) {isNaN(v) ? null : m.push(i); return m;}

  // clean the data (because we know that some values are missing)
  var xNaN = _.reduce(xArray, filterNaN , []);
  var yNaN = _.reduce(yArray, filterNaN , []);
  var include = _.intersection(xNaN, yNaN);
  var fX = _.map(include, function(d) {return xArray[d];});
  var fY = _.map(include, function(d) {return yArray[d];});

  var sumX = _.reduce(fX, sum, 0);
  var sumY = _.reduce(fY, sum, 0);
  var sumX2 = _.reduce(fX, sumSquares, 0);
  var sumY2 = _.reduce(fY, sumSquares, 0);
  var sumXY = _.reduce(fX, function(m, v, i) {return m + v * fY[i];}, 0);

  var n = fX.length;
  var ntor = ( ( sumXY ) - ( sumX * sumY / n) );
  var dtorX = sumX2 - ( sumX * sumX / n);
  var dtorY = sumY2 - ( sumY * sumY / n);

  var r = ntor / (Math.sqrt( dtorX * dtorY )); // Pearson ( http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node122.html )
  var m = ntor / dtorX; // y = mx + b
  var b = ( sumY - m * sumX ) / n;

  // console.log(r, m, b);
  return {r: r, m: m, b: b};
}
```

I have finding correlation between the points i plot using this function which is not written by me. my

```
xarray=[120,110,130,132,120,118,134,105,120,0,0,0,0,137,125,120,127,120,160,120,148]

yarray=[80,70,70,80,70,62,69,70,70,62,90,42,80,72,0,0,0,0,78,82,68,60,58,82,60,76,86,82,70]
```

I can t able to understand the function perfectly. Can anybody explain it with the data i pasted here. I also wanted to remove the zeros getting calculated from this function.

Comment: I don't see any D3 code in there, so I've retagged.

Comment: Yeah no problem can you help me in the explanation?

Answer (score 1):

`// Pearson` http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node122.html
`var r = ntor / (Math.sqrt( dtorX * dtorY ));`

it looks like this example uses the [Pearson Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)

You might be able to understand what is happening in this code better by comparing it to [another JavaScript Implementation](https://gist.github.com/matt-west/6500993//) of the Pearson Correlation

Answer (score 0):

I made my version, including all dependencies functions in "Pearson function". Like: dot, mean, variance, bsxfun (inspired by Matlab)

```
function pearson(ar1, ar2){
    function mean(array){
        let nmean = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++)
            nmean += array[i]
        return nmean/array.length
    }
    function dot(ar1,ar2){
        let result = 0
        if(ar1.length!=ar2.length)
            return undefined
        for(var i in ar1)
            result += ar1[i]*ar2[i]

        return result
    }
    function pseudo_bsxfun(array, number, operator){
        switch(operator){
            case '+':
                for(var i in array)
                    array[i] += number
                break
            case '-':
                for(var i in array)
                    array[i] -= number
                break
            case '*':
                for(var i in array)
                    array[i] *= number
                break
            case '/':
                for(var i in array)
                    array[i] /= number
                break


        }
        return array
    }
    function cov(ar1, ar2){
        let nmean1 = mean(ar1)
        let nmean2 = mean(ar2)
        let cov = []

        nmean1 = pseudo_bsxfun(ar1, nmean1, '-')
        nmean2 = pseudo_bsxfun(ar2, nmean2, '-')

        return dot(nmean1, nmean2)/(ar1.length-1)
    }

    function variance(array){
        let nmean = mean(array)
        let result = 0

        for(var i in array){
            result += Math.pow(array[i]-nmean, 2)
        }
        return result/(array.length-1)
    }

    return cov(ar1, ar2)/Math.sqrt( variance(ar1)*variance(ar2) )
}
```